# Restoring Mysql dump from java: why does it hang the process?

Tags: java, mysql, process, runtime, dump

I'm trying to restore a Mysql dump from a Java app.
I'm using this code:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try {
                   comando = "mysql -u root -ppass -e \"source " + path + "\\sql\\backup.sql\" legapelis" ; 

                   Process proceso = rt.exec(comando);
                   System.out.println("ejecutando");
                   System.out.println(comando);


                   proceso.getInputStream().close();
                   proceso.getOutputStream().close();
                   proceso.getErrorStream().close();


                   completado = proceso.waitFor();
                   if (completado != 0) {
                       System.out.println("error");
                       addActionError(getText("backup.errcopia") + ": " + String.valueOf(completado));
                       consultarCopias();
                       return "error";
                   }
                   System.out.println("fin");


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    addActionError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    consultarCopias();
                    return "error";
                }
```

But the Mysql process that is opened by this code never ends. It hangs and if I kill it, the Mysql service stops working fine (I must restart it). I've tried a lot of codes: closing streams, reading it... but with the same result.

Any hint?

Excuse me if my English isn't so good.

Thank's

Ps: I've tried to add the -v option to the command to read it from inputstream. It start reading but then it hangs again (and it dosn't finish reading the output of the command: it stops suddenly)

Comment: if you were to run that command in a terminal, does the mysql process normally terminate itself once it is finished with its operation?

Comment: Because you closed all the streams, and they're now blocking everything. Read the JavaDoc for `Process`

Comment: From a terminal, the command works fine

Comment: I believe the answer from this post will address your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008526/runtime-getruntime-execcmd-hanging

Comment: EMacOttawa, now I'm solved it by analysing the SQL file in a Java method; but I'll take a look. Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I changed the procedure because I couldn't solve this problem. Now, I read the SQL file and I create an ArrayList with the sentences and I execute them by myself.

Thank's everybody for your support.

Answer (score 1):

JavaDoc for `Process`:

> The created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All
>   its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be
>   redirected to the parent process through three streams
>   (getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), getErrorStream()). The parent
>   process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the
>   subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer
>   size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write
>   the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause
>   the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

You need to read from these streams, not close them.

Comment: It is a bit tricky, try to read and test this: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO07-J.+Do+not+let+external+processes+block+on+IO+buffers and in general, if possible, try to use ProcessBuilder: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: tb; I've tried the examples from that link (with Runtime and  ProcessBuilder both) and the result is the same.

With the redirect solution, for example, it stops at the line "c = is.read()"

Comment: It seems like Inputstream has no data to read and the call blocks the thread.

I could run it in a separate thread but I'll have the same problem; if I don't consume the stream, waitFor will block too.