# Spawning a process using ssh and java

Tags: java, bash, ssh

I know you can run a script via Bash terminal using the following command:

```
ssh -n -f user@host "sh -c 'nohup /path/to/file/test.sh > /path/to/file/test.out 2>&1 &'"
```

When we run this same command using the following java command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "comand" ).waitFor();
```

It doesn't work. In order to test this, I am running a simple .sh script that prints "hello world" and outputs it to a 'test.out' file. I'm not getting a runtime error, I'm just not seeing that output.

Note: I correctly place '\' escape characters in the "command" area.

How can we do this using java?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass in the path to your shell in which you want to run your command. And then you can try other overloaded versions of the method with clearly separating the different pieces:

[Java Runtime API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

[Runtime example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008526/runtime-getruntime-execcmd-hanging)

Comment: What do you mean the path to my shell? Do you mean instead of 'sh' I use /bin/sh? And if so, since the command includes an SSH, shouldn't it simply run that quoted query on the server I ssh'd to? Thanks!