# running linux command from java, error 500, Cannot run program No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, shell

im trying to send an email with a Linux command from Java, i admit i don't know much about Linux but i think iv'e tried everything and i'm just really confused, if someone could shed some light for it would be great

i export the application to a war file and upload it to a linux server (CentOS)

so here's what i'm doing: i'm triggering the code from a servlet with the browser

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String cmd = "mail -s \"Test Email\" my@email.com < /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/slots_dashboard/alert_mail.txt";

    //String cmd = "whoami"; //returns tomcat

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    Process proc = pb.start();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    String s = null;

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        resp.getWriter().println(s);
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        resp.getWriter().println(s);
    }
}
```

the error i get is:
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot run program "mail -s "Test Email" my@email.com < /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/slots_dashboard/alert_mail.txt": error=2, No such file or directory

if i change the command to whoami i get tomcat in the response, i even went to the servers computer and tried the command from there and there was no problem. guys, please help :(

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if that the reason, but all the examples I've seen on how to use `ProcessBuilder` use a list of strings as arguments to the constructor (a string per parameter), instead of one long string with the entire command.
Maybe it's worth trying something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mail", "-s", "\"Test Email\"", "my@email.com", "<", "/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/slots_dashboard/alert_mail.txt");
```

I'm shooting in the dark here, obviously. But worth a shot.

Comment: I'd say your shot in the dark has hit the target.  +1

Comment: hey thanks, it seems like the right direction, only now the program just hangs and the the browser is in a perpetual state of loading, any ideas?

also, i already tried to do the errorStream and InputStream reading in 2 seperate threads, i basically copied the code from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008526/runtime-getruntime-execcmd-hanging

Comment: probably the `<` not working as expected and the mail command awaits the email content

Comment: another guess: instead of using the `< path-to-file` at the end of the command, use `redirectInput` to read the file's content as input . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput(java.io.File)

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your tomcat user doesn't have access to that file. Did you use the same username when trying that command manually?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, i checked and i should have access,
further investigation shows that any command i try that has no parameters works fine, but commands with parameters return errors, i guess i'm not executing it properly from java, i just don't know how