# Curl commend not executing when its being called from application

Tags: shell, curl

I am executing one shell script, which contains the following curl command.

```sh
FIRST=`curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'How-Many: 1' -d '{"filters": { "jobstreamFilter": { "jobStreamName":"'$JOBSTREAM_NAME'","workstationName": "'$WORKSTATION_NAME'"}}}' https://$IWA_HOST:31116/twsd/model/jobstream/header/query -H "Authorization: Basic $CREDS"`
```

When I execute the shell script from CLI it works fine, but when I call the script from the application, this curl command is not executed. The rest of all the echo statements in the script are printing except `FIRST`.

Comment: share the code what you are trying from application

Comment: I just calling the Shell script from the application with passing parameter like path of the shell script & the JobName ,and its being called  . String[] cmd = { inputEletpath, jobName};   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];                                 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new nputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  String jobSchDetails; String jobStatusResult = "";  while ((jobSchDetails = reader.readLine()) != null) {  addAuditTrailEntry("Script output: " + jobSchDetails);jobStatusResult = jobStatusResult+jobSchDetails;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008526/runtime-getruntime-execcmd-hanging)